# How to capture only the first few letters using jQuery filter function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm changing the background via CSS if the text "Off" is found.  Works fine.

```
$('td:contains("Off")').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == "Off";
}).css({"background":"#667881", "color":"white"});
```

Is there a way to amend the jQuery .filter function above to only test the first 3 characters (capturing only 'Off')?  Some of textfields contain more:

"Off some more words"

Ones like these aren't targeted via my code above even though they contain 'Off'

However, I don't want ones like this to be targeted: "some more words Off"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a substring to your `$(this).text()` in the filter function, like so

```
$('td').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().substring(0,3) == "Off";
}).css({"background":"#667881", "color":"white"});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)**  with regex **[`^Off`](https://regex101.com/r/rT9bW3/1)** , which only matches string start with `Off`

```js
$('td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().match(/^Off/);
}).css({
  "background": "#667881",
  "color": "white"
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Off
    </td>
    <td>omff
    </td>
    <td>off
    </td>
    <td>coff
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use match():

```js
$('td:contains("Off")').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().match("^Off");
}).css({"background":"#667881", "color":"white"});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Off some more words</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some more words Off</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>some more Off words Off</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `^` matches only if the text begins with `Off`

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use $(this).text().substring(0,3)?

It's not a filter functionality but it should do the job.

Hope it helps! :)